# How to get all documents in given Documents Set in SP2016 using JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, jsom, caml

I have client-side Javascript on a SharePoint page. It must change the Title of every Document present **in a specific Documents Set**.

That Documents Set is one of many, in a huge documents library (before you ask: still within Microsoft's recommendations). Therefore I cannot afford to iterate on every item of the Library and only *then* filter the ones that are in the Documents Set. The query must make the **Server** do the filtering.

I have found that the general consensus is that the Documents Sets should be treated as folders, and that the filtering should be done as follows :

```
var libTitle = "My Library";
var subFolder = "My Subfolder";

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
oLibrary = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(libTitle);

var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery(); //This creates a Caml query that takes everything...
query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(libTitle+"/"+subFolder); //...but then this should restrict to only the targetted Documents Set

var queryResults = oLibrary.getItems(query);
var allDocs = clientContext.loadQuery(queryResults , "Include(ID, Title, ContentType, ContentTypeId, File)" );



clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
        for (var i=0; i< allDocs.length; i++) {
            console.log("Found Item with ID '"+allDocs[i].get_item('ID')+"' ('"+allDocs[i].get_item('Title')+"').");
        }       
    }),
    null
);
```

My issue is that ***query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl* seems to be completely ignored**... I clearly see every library item in the results (or at least, all the root folders).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `folderServerRelativeUrl` doesn't seem to be properly created. Suppose you have a site at `/sites/yoursite` Url containing a library named TestLib with a folder TestFolder, then the `folderServerRelativeUrl` will be `'/sites/yoursite/TestLib/TestFolder'`. If the site is the root site not under any managed path then the `folderServerRelativeUrl` will be `'/TestLib/TestFolder'`.

The other way of testing whther a folder server relative Url is correct is by using `var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderServerRelativeUrl);`

Comment: Thank you that might be the reason because I'm on a managed path. I'll test it and come back to you. That said, I'm baffled that SharePoint returns EVERYTHING instead of NOTHING when it doesn't recognize the path.

Comment: That was the solution. Instead of just "libTitle+"/"+subFolder", I used "/MyManagedPath/MySite/"+libTitle+"/"+subFolder" and it worked. I guess for anyone else, replacing "MyManagedPath" with "sites" should do the trick. Thanks!